# How to check if Core Data has already a value?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I have this code which gets the id and name from one cell.. and then when I select a row I have to save this choice and send it to Core Data... But for example: If I have already a city with a duplicated name.. How I can stop adding it?

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *villesR = [NSEntityDescription
                                   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ville"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context];


[villesR setValue:idVille forKey:@"idV"];
[villesR setValue:nomville forKey:@"nom"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tidane,

When you need to check if an object is already there or not, you need to set up a fetch request and use a specific predicate. In your case you could simple fetch against `Ville` and see if you have  `idV` already. I suppose `idV` is like an identifier for your `Ville`. Checking the `nom` could be the same but you could have two `cities` with the same name in two different places in the world.

**@alpz** solutions is ok. In addition you could also set the fecth limit to 1:

```
[request setFetchLimit:1];
```

Otherwise you could simply do

```
NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];    
if(count == 0) {

     // add the new city here
}
```

instead of

```
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

**@Phillip Mills** is saying that you could use `NSManagedObject` subclasses instead of using Key Value Coding access. I think it's easier to work with properties of class instead of plain string keys.

So, once you have created a `Ville` subclass ([organising-core-data-for-ios](http://blog.chrismiles.info/2011/06/organising-core-data-for-ios.html)), you could just create a category for it, called `Ville+Extension`, and create a method like the following:

```
+ (Ville *)villeWithUniqueName:(NSString *)name withManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ville" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nom = %@", name];
    [request setFetchLimit:1];

    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];        

    Ville* theVille = nil;  

    if ([results count] == 0)
    {
        theVille = // create the new here
    }
    else
    {
        theVille = (Ville*)[results objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [request release]; // if you don't use ARC

    return theVille;
}
```

Then, use that category (after having imported) like:

```
Ville* theVille = [Ville villeWithUniqueName:@"yourName" withManagedObjectContext:yourContext];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much... I finally got the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the core data for its existence before you are saving it. This is how I handled the same situation.

```
NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext* context=[Server serverInfo].context;
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Coupon" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Upc=%@",[[ar objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"upc_code"]]];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]; 
[request release];

if ([results count] == 0)
{
    //core data does not have an entry with the upc code(in my case) that i am searching
}
else
{
    // core data have already an entry with that upc code
}
```

This results array will show you if that entry exists or not. Let me know if you have any queries..happy coding!

Comment: It founds it.. But it adds and empty row... I don't get it too much :S

Comment: do the code for adding the entry only if the array count is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to create a City class and a class method for it such as:

```
+ (City *)cityWithUniqueName:(NSString *)name;
```

In there, you would look up an existing core data object with the name and return it.  If it isn't found, create one using `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` and return that.

Comment: I can possibly visualise that.. But I'm really lost... Create a class City with idV and name.. After that i make all the fetch?